# Edit debug AndroidManifest.xml with Expo plugins

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using a custom expo plugin to integrate a native SDK in a Expo project and I need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml of the debug folder.

With expo plugins, I can use withAndroidManifest to edit the main AndroidManifest but not the debug one.

Does someone know if there is a way to achieve this?